# Opening and Editing Numerical Data from a Text File and Putting the Result into a New File, C++

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

(I got it!) Okay, be warned that I am very new to C++ and programming in general. The end goal for this program is to open a text file, edit the numbers in the text file (square positive numbers and double negatives), create a new file and print the name of the new file on the first line, and print the new values in the new file. The program needs to stop after encountering -99 in the original file but not before changing it and printing it to the new file.

Here's my original mess:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>  
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int value;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("exampleFile.txt"); // Create file
    myfile << "exampleFile.txt\n";  // Print file name in file

    string line; 
    ifstream farrisFile;
    farrisFile.open("Farris.txt");
    if (farrisFile.is_open())
    {
        (farrisFile >> value);
        while (value > 0)
        {
            myfile << value * value << endl;
        }
        do
        {
            value * 2;
        } 
        while (value > -99);
    }




    myfile.close();
    farrisFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the correct program except for that it prints -198 twice at the end but that's a simple fix. The issue was that the file I was reading was in the wrong location and the -1717986920 was underflow. 
Here's the program a bit more refined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int value;      // Establish a variable to use for file values

    ifstream farrisFile;
    farrisFile.open("Farris.txt");      // Open Farris.txt

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("TristenStokes.txt");   // Create file
    myfile << "TristenStokes.txt\n";    // Print file name in file


        (farrisFile >> value);          // Read first line of Farris.txt
        while (value > -99)         // Establish sentinel 
        {
                while (value > 0)
               {
                    myfile << value * value << endl;
                    farrisFile >> value;
                    break;
                }
                    while (value <= 0)
                       {
                            myfile << value * 2 << endl;
                            farrisFile >> value;
                            break;
                       }                
            continue;
        }
    if (value == -99)
        {
            myfile << value * 2 << endl;            
        }


    myfile.close();
    farrisFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You read an integer from the file by writing `farrisFile >> value`. Note, the error is in the line `while(value > 0)` because, if the value you read from file is positive, it will always remain positive. You are never reading a new value from the file again inside the loop. Resulting in a infinite loop. What you want is read an integer from the file as long as you don't get a -99. May be this is what you want.

```
while(1){
    farrisFile >> value;
    if(value < 0){
        myFile << 2*value << endl;
        if(value == -99)    break;
    }
    else{
        myFile << value * value << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: That resulted in this being printed to the file (which is a step forward, nevertheless! :) )                                                                                             exampleFile.txt                                                                                               -1717986920                                                                                                    (And this number repeating until the end of the text file)

Comment: Which is similar to the code I have produced before seeing your response, but mine only printed -1717986920 once which is :             
          // if (farrisFile.is_open())
 {
 

  (farrisFile >> value);
  while (value > 0)
  {
   myfile << value * value << endl;
   
   continue;
  }
  do
  {
   myfile << value * 2  << endl;
   
   continue;
  } 
  while (value > -99);
   
 }

Comment: Can you post the input file? What is the value of the variable value?

Comment: Here's the contents of the input file:                                                                                                          
5
8
-3
-2
15
0
-1
5
-99

Comment: It would be an infinite loop because the first value is positive. So your program would never exit. It will keep on printing endless 25. It is always a good practice to write some form of algorithm (Pseudocode, Flowchart etc) before writing actual code. And then from the algorithm, implement your program.

Comment: My program didn;t create an infinite loop though?

Comment: Would be better if you put your code in here. I copied your code and also your next modification. It fell in an infinite loop

Comment: I put up the code that was printing -171986920 just once in the new file

Comment: I think there's a better way to share code rather than suggesting an edit. Plus, the code I have received, falls in a infinite loop. I am not sure why you are getting such output as you saying. If you follow your code closely and apply simple logic, you would see that there's no way of getting out of `while(value > 0) { myFIle << value * value << endl; continue; }` loop. Because if value is once positive, it is never getting negative again inside the loop. May be you wanted to put `break` instead of `continue`?

Comment: I'm telling you what it output into the filen], and even with the breaks it output the same thing I stated before.

Comment: Also if there is a better way I apologize but I'm new to this site so please bear with me.

Comment: You can try paste.ubuntu.com or pastebin for codesharing.

Comment: I got it fixed, I just had a stupid file placement error (oops).